# Basic Authentication with lightswitch 2012

Tags: iis-7, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I am trying to use basic authentication on my lightswitch 2012 (html) project, but i get an unauthorized error when trying to get something from the database.
is there a way to use basic authentication with this tool?

Comment: Is the whole page unauthorized? Or does it say you are unauthorized to run the query?

Comment: it starts off in the login screen and i get a prompt from my browser, i then put in my credentials and it goes to the next page. in this page i constantly get prompted even though my credentials are correct, and when i 'x' out of the popup i get and unathorized error where there should be data form the db. Everything comes up ok when i run anonymous

Comment: In Visual Studio, is the application set up for Forms Authentication, or Windows Authentication?